# TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be str, not None

Tags: python, json

I'm create new project

I create two function. First func normally run, but second function not working

**First func:**

```
#it's work

def twitter(adress):
    reqURL = request.urlopen("https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=%s" % adress)
    encodingData = reqURL.headers.get_content_charset()
    jsonLoad = json.loads(reqURL.read().decode(encodingData))
    print("Sharing:", jsonLoad['count'])
```

**Second func:**

```
#Doesn't work

def facebook(adress):
    reqURL = request.urlopen("https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=%s&format=json" % adress)
    encodingData = reqURL.headers.get_content_charset()
    jsonLoad = json.loads(reqURL.read().decode(encodingData))
    print("Sharing:", jsonLoad['share_count'])
```

How to fix second func(facebook)

**I get the error for facebook func:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/myproject/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    facebook(url)
  File "/myproject/main.py", line 15, in facebook
    jsonLoad = json.loads(reqURL.read().decode(encodingData))
TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

**twitter func out:**

```
Sharing: 951
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook response doesn't include a `charset` parameter indicating the encoding used:

```
>>> from urllib import request
>>> adress = 'www.zopatista.com'
>>> reqURL = request.urlopen("https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=%s" % adress)
>>> reqURL.info().get('content-type')
'application/json;charset=utf-8'
>>> reqURL = request.urlopen("https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=%s&format=json" % adress)
>>> reqURL.info().get('content-type')
'application/json'
```

Note the `charset=utf-8` part in the Twitter response.

The JSON standard states that the *default* characterset is UTF-8, so pass that to the [`get_content_charset()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_content_charset):

```
encodingData = reqURL.headers.get_content_charset('utf8')
jsonLoad = json.loads(reqURL.read().decode(encodingData))
```

Now, when no content `charset` parameter is set, the default `'utf8'` is returned instead.

Note that Facebook's JSON response contains a *list* of matches; because you are passing in just one URL, you could take just the first result:

```
print("Sharing:", jsonLoad[0]['share_count'])
```

Comment: how to making? I don't understand

Comment: Thanks but i get new error :/ i'm sorry :/

`facebook(url)
  File "/myproject/main.py", line 17, in facebook
    print("Sharing:", jsonLoad['share_count'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: @Ali: Facebook returns a **list**; use `jsonLoad[0]['share_count']`

Comment: @Marjijn Pieters thank you it's work :) i'm so happy thank you :)